# python2 - read bytes as signed chars from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary, hex

I wish to read bytes as signed chars from file!
for example, the input file content as below (16 bytes):

```
f5 00 b7 47 16 00 14 09 1c 17 5d 6c d9 c8 f3 eb
```

The I wish the output is (16 signed char):

```
-11 0 -73 71 22 0 20 9 28 23 93 108 -39 -56 -13 -21
```

The file read api return a string object.I need a list as above.

Comment: Just a reminder, python 2.7 has an end of life date of January 1st 2020.  Im sorry i cant answer your question but I would like to encourage you to move towards python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there's a better way, but this works

```
>>> import binascii, struct
>>> s = 'f5 00 b7 47 16 00 14 09 1c 17 5d 6c d9 c8 f3 eb'
>>> bs = s.replace(' ', '')
>>> struct.unpack(len(bs) / 2 * 'b', binascii.unhexlify(bs))
(-11, 0, -73, 71, 22, 0, 20, 9, 28, 23, 93, 108, -39, -56, -13, -21)
```